# How to include splash screen with Remote Display API?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a Cast app with the Remote Display API, and would like to show a splash screen while content is loading. I know it's possible to include a splash with a Styled Media Receiver or Custom Media Receiver, but it seems these are mutually exclusive with the Remote Display Receiver.

Is there any way to include a splash screen (or other styling) with a Remote Display Receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no separate mechanism (like the one in Styled Receiver) for showing a splash screen; what is shown on TV is fully coming from your phone and the view that you have mirrored so you'd need to include that in the view that you are mirroring.